# How to use port.on() and port.emit() with each other

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to use a page-worker and a pageMod together using port.on() and port.emit(), but the signals from define.js do not have any effect on the pageMod's port.on()... Is this the proper way to use port.on() and port.emit() or is chaining the two together this way not allowed?

index.js:

```
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptWhen: "ready",
  contentScriptFile: [
    data.url("jquery.js"),
    data.url("jquery-ui.min.js"),
    data.url("define.js")
  ],
  onAttach: function(worker){
      worker.port.on("getWord", function(word) {
          console.log(word);
          worker.port.emit("newWord", word);
      });
      worker.port.on("updatedWord", function(URL){
          console.log(URL);
      });
    }
});

dictionaryRef.Page({
    contentScriptWhen: "ready",
    contentScriptFile: [
      data.url("jquery.js"),
      data.url("jquery-ui.min.js"),
      data.url("define.js"),
    ],
    contentURL: "http://www.dictionary.com/browse/",
    onAttach: function(worker){
        worker.port.on("newWord", function(word) {
            console.log(word);
            self.contentURL = "http://www.dictionary.com/browse/" + word;
            worker.port.emit("updatedWord", self.contentURL);
        });
    }
});
```

define.js:

```
$(window).dblclick(function() {
    var selected = getSelected();
    if (selected!="") {
        calldictionary(selected);
        var completedURL = "http://www.dictionary.com/browse/" + selected;
        pageMod.port.emit("getWord", selected);
        $('#define').dialog("open");
        dictionaryRef.contentURL = completedURL;
    }
});



function getSelected() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return '';
}
```

Basically, getSelected() will capture a highlighted word and then the "dblclick" binding should send a signal via port.emit() that the pageMod should receive, then pass onto a page-worker to change its URL, which would allow me to access the DOM and scrape the dictionary definition so that it can be displayed in the main window in a popup. At the moment, none of the port.emit() statements work.

Comment: I'm not an sdk guy but did you see this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port#port.emit%28%29

Comment: Yes I've read through the MDN documentation but it hasn't helped me very much :/

Comment: `window` has a `getSelection()` method, but not a `getSelection` property.

Comment: Are you sure? The way I'm using getSelection at the moment works fine

Comment: Perhaps the parentheses on method calls are optional.  I haven't gotten your add-on running yet b/c jquery-ui is complaining about `"jQuery is not defined"`, which doesn't make sense to me since jquery is listed first in `contentScriptFile`.  One thing is, though, your content script looks for a selection, but is triggered by a pageMod attach event, and selection of content generally occurs after a page attaches.  Usually scripts that access selections would go though a `contextMenu` with `SelectionContext` context, or an `ActionButton`.